# shell cgi script to ping ipaddress

Tags: shell, cgi, ping

How to ping particular IP Address in cgi using shell script.
Here i have a code, which works fine, when i run it on console.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
ipaddr="192.168.1.1"
ping -c 2 $ipaddr &> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  PingStatus="<font color='green'>Success</font>"
 # Following line is to just to test on console output
  echo "ping is Success"
  echo $PingStatus
else
  PingStatus="<font color='red'>Failed</font>"
 # Following line is to just to test on console output
  echo "ping is Failed"
  echo $PingStatus
fi
```

output:

```
 Content-type: text/html
 ping is Success
<font color='green'>Success</font>
```

But when i run through browser, getting ping status as Failed[else part is executed].Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What tool are you using to serve this cgi as a webpage? Apache, Nginx, etc. ?

Comment: You can shorten the script a little by throwing out the explicit check of exit code `[ $? -eq 0 ]`. Just write `if ping -c 2 $ipaddr &> /dev/null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the above.. by enabling the permission to ping

command to enable permission

```
sudo chmod u+s `which ping`
```

Comment: Nice! In the future, you can use `ping -c 2 $ipaddr 2>&1` to show error messages on the page instead of throwing them away